# Selenium & C# - run test cases sequentially for all browsers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium (WebDriver) and C# and have a question regarding running tests.

I have developed a number of tests and they are all working as I expect.  I am able to execute them in FireFox, IE and Chrome but I have to manually alter the definition of my driver initialization between runs.

What I want is to run all tests in IE, then re-execute in Chrome then once more in FireFox  and I have not figured out how I could do that.

Anyone done something similar?

Any thoughts are appreciated.
Thanks

Sean

Comment: You can find the answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164738/sequential-execution-of-webdriver-suite-c-sharp-selenium-grid-all-local

Comment: What are you using to run your tests? If you are using Microsoft's Testing suite (Lab Management) there is a way to alter your build process template.